# How do I wake the ESP8266 from deep sleep on a specific date and time?

Tags: esp8266

I'd like to put my ESP8266 into deep sleep and then wake it up at at specific date and time, [roughly] to the second.

Edit: Unfortunately, ESP8266 deep sleep doesn't support values greater than about 3.5 hours. I tried sleeping for an hour at a time until the desired time is reached, but found that it's not very accurate; often dozens seconds of drift on each wake, adding up to many minutes of drift after several hours.

Edit: I want to wake every 24 hours at a specific time. A few seconds per week drift is more than acceptable, as I'll be re-syncing the clock every 24 hours or so.

Edit: I'm using `WAKE_RF_DISABLED` to disable WiFi to save power on wake, so when it wakes up, there is usually no internet connection to check the time (I want to connect to WiFi only once every 24h).

Comment: Over what period of time do you expect one-second accuracy? This is important.

Comment: Every 24 hours at a specific time, but I'd like a solution that I can use flexibly, so perhaps wake every few days.

Comment: You need 1ppm or better if you want 1 second accuracy over a period on 1 week. That's not going to be easy or cheap. For a cheap RTC the accuracy will be limited by the crystal itself, not by the chip that counts the clock cycles.

Comment: Are you sure? "The [DS3231 at ±3.5ppm] maintains the RTC to within ±2 minutes per year accuracy from -40°C to +85°C" (Source: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf)

Comment: Two minutes per year is 120 seconds over 52 weeks...worse than 2 seconds per week drift. I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Well, according to Maxim, that is still "extremely accurate" and I'm inclined to agree. I'm not designing a GPS satellite.

Comment: As you wish, but you changed the requirements. You said "wake every few days" and "on a specific...date" then you later said that you will be "re-syncing the clock every 24 hours or so". Whatever works for you. Peace.

Comment: Yes, I realised that I was being too demanding; I appreciate that to the second over a year would be impossible with the DS3231, and I definitely don't need that level of accuracy. I'm more than happy with 2 seconds of drift per week. Peace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the ESP8266 doesn't have a *[real](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/modules/rtctime/)* onboard RTC (i.e. it's not capable of keeping very accurate time while in deep sleep) and is limited to a [short time period](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/modules/rtctime/#rtctimedsleep), one solution is to use an external RTC (real time clock) but there is a way of doing it without.

Below are 3 approaches, the first two involve a [DS3231](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) RTC (quite easy to get as a module). For low power, I prefer DS3231 over DS1307, since DS3231 modules seem to work fine at 2.6V (whereas DS1307 modules seem to require at least 3.3V... or more like 4.5V according to the [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf)). The 3rd approach is useful if you don't want to add an external RTC.

> "The DS3231 is a low-cost, extremely accurate I2C real-time clock (RTC)".
> The DS3231 "maintains the RTC to within ±2 minutes per year accuracy from -40°C to +85°C"

**Solution 1: Periodically wake the MCU and check the external RTC**

Probably, the most energy efficient solution (compared to using the alarm solution below) would be to wake the ESP8266 from deep sleep periodically to check the time on the external RTC and depending on desired accuracy, deep sleep for shorter periods as you approach the target wake time (e.g. wake and check the RTC every minute once you're about 10 mins away from the target time).

To save power, before sleeping the ESP8266, you can simply use a transistor connected to GPIO to turn off the Vcc power supply on the DS3231 module (it'll use the onboard 2032 battery while no power is supplied). Don't forget to turn off the I2C pull-ups too, as they can provide parasite power to the RTC. You can also just disconnect GND.

If restarted with WiFi off (`ESP.deepSleep(1e6, WAKE_RF_DISABLED)`), the ESP8266 only needs to wake for about 200 ms consuming 20 mA to check the DS3231 if it's time to wake up fully. This is probably the most energy efficient you can get with wanting to keep accurate time.

**Solution 2: Set an alarm on the external RTC to wake the MCU**

Using the DS3231, the SQW pin can be connected to the ESP8266 RST pin via a [monostable circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/644782/288848). The monostable circuit is important because the RST pin can't stay low, as it won't boot. The monostable circuit creates a pulse on the RST pin when the DS3231 SQW pin goes low.

A note on power consumption: The ESP8266 should consume only 20 µA in deep sleep, but DS3231 modules actually tend to use about **1 mA** when powered on (which is required to trigger the alarm), probably because of the EEPROM on the module. That power consumption is significant if you're designing a low power system. This is why this 2nd solution is less energy efficient compared to the 1st solution.

The following code will set an alarm to a specific time, and when the RST pin is pulled low (based on the SQW output of the DS3231), the ESP8266 then wakes up. Make sure you uncomment `SLEEP_DT` and set a date and time to wake at a specific date and time (of course, you can set this programmatically to any date and time), otherwise it'll wake up every *n* seconds (value of `SLEEP_SECONDS`) but that might also be useful (ESP8266 deep sleep time isn't very accurate).

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

// TODO: NTPClient is redundant; replace with native
// ESP8266 NTP functions (configTime and localtime)
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#include <RTClib.h>

#define WIFI_SSID "Your WiFi SSID"
#define WIFI_PASS "Your WiFi password"

// uncomment to wake up at specific date and time
//#define SLEEP_DT
#define SLEEP_DT_YEAR 2022
#define SLEEP_DT_MONTH 12
#define SLEEP_DT_DAY 02
#define SLEEP_DT_HOUR 15
#define SLEEP_DT_MINUTE 50
#define SLEEP_DT_SECOND 25

#define SLEEP_SECONDS 10 // easier for testing

RTC_DS3231 rtc;
WiFiUDP udp;
NTPClient ntp(udp);

void print_date(const DateTime& dt);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) { delay(1); }
  
  Serial.println('\n');
  Serial.println("Hello RTC wake deep sleep");
  
  Serial.println("Init DS3231");
  if(!rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("DS3231 failed");
    while (true) { delay(1); }
  }

  // not needed
  rtc.disable32K();

  // not used
  rtc.disableAlarm(2);

  // apparently can lead to problems if not cleared
  rtc.clearAlarm(1);
  rtc.clearAlarm(2);

  // stop oscillating; allows alarm to work
  rtc.writeSqwPinMode(DS3231_OFF);
  
  Serial.println("Init WiFi");
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
  
  Serial.println("Connecting to " WIFI_SSID);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
  }
  Serial.print("Connected, IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  ntp.begin();
  bool ntpOk = ntp.update();

  if (rtc.lostPower()) {
    Serial.println("RTC lost power, setting time");
    if (ntpOk) {
      Serial.println("Using time from NTP client");
      rtc.adjust(DateTime(ntp.getEpochTime()));
    }
    else {
      // untested code
      Serial.println("NTP unavailable, using time of build");
      rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    }
  }
  
  Serial.print("Date and time set to: ");
  print_datetime(rtc.now());

#ifdef SLEEP_DT

  DateTime alarm(
    SLEEP_DT_YEAR,
    SLEEP_DT_MONTH,
    SLEEP_DT_DAY,
    SLEEP_DT_HOUR,
    SLEEP_DT_MINUTE,
    SLEEP_DT_SECOND);

  Serial.print("Setting alarm for date: ");
  print_datetime(alarm);
    
  if (!rtc.setAlarm1(alarm, DS3231_A1_Date)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to set alarm");
  }

#else

  // sleep for set seconds for the purposes of testing
  Serial.print("Setting alarm for seconds: ");
  Serial.print(SLEEP_SECONDS);
  Serial.println(" seconds");
  if (!rtc.setAlarm1(rtc.now() + TimeSpan(SLEEP_SECONDS), DS3231_A1_Second)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to set alarm");
  }
  
#endif // SLEEP_DT

  Serial.println("Going into deep sleep (wake on RST low)");
  Serial.flush();
  ESP.deepSleep(0);
}

void print_datetime(const DateTime& dt) {
  char df[] = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss";
  Serial.println(dt.toString(df));
}

void loop() { }
```

Here it is in action...

[image: Arduino IDE and output]

Note: The time jumps because I chopped out a few frames to save you from being bored (no smoke and mirrors, I promise).

**Solution 3: Use only the internal RTC**

Keeping with the low power theme: to use the internal RTC in deep sleep, you have to keep sleeping for *n* seconds until desired seconds elapse. You can keep track of how many seconds have elapsed by using the RTC memory. This approach allows you to implement time keeping without having to add an external RTC, and without having to reconnect connect to WiFi every hour. However, I have found the drift to be quite substantial (many seconds per hour), so this is probably useful only when accuracy is not a major concern.

Comment: the ESP8266 has an onboard RTC capable of keeping time while in deep sleep

Comment: "Despite being named RTC, the RTC is not really a Real Time Clock in the normal sense of the word. While it does keep a counter ticking while the module is sleeping, the accuracy with which it does so is highly dependent on the temperature of the chip.": https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/modules/rtctime/

Comment: "number of microseconds to sleep for. Maxmium value is 4294967295us, or ~71 minutes.": https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/modules/rtctime/#rtctimedsleep

Comment: @Juraj Updated answer, thanks.

Comment: You are fooling yourself if you think your cheap RTC module is accurate to 1 second over a period of more than a few hours. You need to carefully calibrate the RTC and maintain it at a constant temperature if you want better accuracy.

Comment: I'm not sure I can agree with you. Maxim is a pretty reputable company. Unless the datasheet is lying... "The DS3231 is a low-cost, extremely accurate I2C real-time clock (RTC)" https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf

Comment: Also... "maintains the RTC to within ±2 minutes per year accuracy from -40°C to +85°C"

Comment: @ElliotAlderson FYI, I have flagged your comment as unfriendly (which is against the code of conduct). I suggest you re-think how you communicate with others. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/conduct#unfriendly-language

Comment: I will try to be more diplomatic. Your proposed solution will not be able to provide an accuracy of 1 second over a period of more than a few days, as stated in the Maxim documentation. The words "extremely accurate" mean different things to different people.

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy (and most people probably would be happy) with the accuracy improvement that the DS3231 offers over the ESP8266 deep sleep RTC (which seems to drift by several seconds over an hour). If you're sleeping repeatedly to get to 24h, then that drift is quite bad... many minutes. The DS3231 is certainly a significant improvement on that, don't you think?

Comment: the RTC is updated from NTP if connection to Internet is available

Comment: Yep, if there is an internet connection; not if you're turning WiFi off to save power.

Comment: I noticed that with ESP8266, when waking after deep sleep, the NTP time (using `configTime` and `localtime`) is reset to default; 1970. With an external RTC, of course this isn't a problem.

Comment: @Juraj I was thinking about what you said... did you mean that if `configTime` is used on ESP8266, then `NTPClient` is redundant?

Comment: of course it is redundant

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I wonder why the most popular tutorials for "esp8266 time" point to `NTPClient`; the top 3 results all do, and only until you get to the 4th is `configTime` mentioned.